# Host blocking all but icmp

Tags: networking, iptables, centos7

I'm having a strange issue on a Centos 7 VM host (qemu-kvm).

I have two VMs which, up until a week ago, were working perfectly fine with bridged networking. Now they can no longer access anything on the network or on the internet (with the exception of the host itself). The only way to get them to communicate with the outside world is by changing the network source to Virtual/NAT. This is obviously not ideal since they're no longer directly attached to my network.

The exception to this is ICMP traffic. I can ping other devices on the network (and internet) while bridged, but all TCP/UDP traffic is blocked.

Tracing back my steps, the last thing I did before this happened was start up the docker service on the host (which was stopped for some reason), but the network connectivity issues only started maybe 10-20 seconds after this. I should note here that I don't have any containers set up on the host.

My gut instinct tells me that there's an iptables rule somewhere that's screwing things up, but I honestly don't know how such a rule could have been created (other than automatically by docker), and I don't know what exactly I should be looking for.

For the record, I have two networks (`192.168.0.0`, `192.168.1.0`) which are segregated on separate VLANs. The host machine has two NICs, one attached to each VLAN, and the VMs are bridged to both networks. `0.0` is connected to the internet, while `1.0` is not. The VM host is not acting as a gateway.

These are my iptables dumps:

- filter: https://pastebin.com/xBLY2Kad
- nat: https://pastebin.com/PFTCA80u
- mangle: https://pastebin.com/PSEH5ubY
- raw: https://pastebin.com/T1x2Xe3H
- security: https://pastebin.com/GbPmCA3E

This is my firewalld config:

```
internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: bridge0
  sources: 
  services: ssh mdns samba-client dhcpv6-client samba mountd rpc-bind nfs ntp dns
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:

cameras (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: bridge1
  sources: 192.168.1.4/32
  services: ntp
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

[EDIT]

I'm adding the output of `iptables -S` here as it's clearly more useful:
https://pastebin.com/wKAtSKPG

In addition, I confirmed it's a firewall issue after I stopped firewalld and was then able to connect to the outside world from the VMs

Answer (score 0):

> My gut instinct tells me that there's an iptables rule somewhere that's screwing things up, but I honestly don't know how such a rule could have been created **(other than automatically by docker)**, and I don't know what exactly I should be looking for.

My guess would be that your instincts are exactly right. [Docker uses IPtables](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/) for its internal routing and mixes your existing rules with its own. I have debugged issues with this setup in the past by comparing the IPtables state before and after the start of the Docker daemon (the delay you experienced is probably the setup time).

If you see that Docker does indeed disturb your setup, you may want to insert the Docker rules manually or move the Docker daemon onto another machine.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like docker is actually making a difference here, though. Stopping the docker service doesn't resolve the issue. I dumped the iptables rules before and after stopping the service, and there was no difference. Starting docker again merely shifted three rules up three lines, but they were all being applied to the `docker0` interface.

Paste is here: https://pastebin.com/k7B6G3tU

Comment: I just completely removed docker from the system and restarted `firewalld`. Issue persists. I'm fairly certain it's some other rule causing me grief.

Comment: Stopping the Docker daemon does not remove the IPtables rules (tested it on my own system), so that might not be enough. If you remove it, use `iptables -F` to flush the tables with `-t filter`, `-t nat` and possibly `-t mangle`. Or restart your system. `firewalld` should then refill the flushed chains.

Comment: Another possibility: you have some `REJECT` rules in your chains, e.g. in the `FORWARD` chain. You may be able to debug the issue by watching the counters of `iptables -nvL` when trying to send packets which are blocked.